# Is 60 seconds long enough to wait for a TCP/IP message to get processed

Tags: linux, tcp, timeout

When a client/server application needs to request data from the client, I send out the request message over the established socket and wait for the response - with a 60 second timeout to 'guarantee' that the server app waits long enough - but not 'forever' for a response.  Occasionally these timeouts get hit, and the server app will fail.  These failures tend to come in bursts.

Is there any way to know when these occur whether they're simply caused by heavy network traffic - and will eventually succeed - or whether they're caused by a harder kind of outage, and will never get a response within a reasonable time?  I.e., is 60 seconds long enough to wait for such a data request over an existing socket - and if not, what would a better timeout value be?  Would the TCP/IP stack (Amazon linux, in this case) end up retrying the transmission shortly after I've given up on it...?

Comment: There is no generic TCP message and there is no upper limit how an arbitrary message should be processed. It is not even clear what you mean with processed: a response that a specific action was finished or that it was started or that the message was received by the application or that it was received by the OS ...  What are reasonable timeouts depend on the specific use case.

Comment: The actual processing time is minuscule - I'm just requesting client input that's already available.  I guess I'm talking about transport delay - i.e. how long to wait for the socket to recover from dropped packets, etc.  Under normal circumstances, the round trip will always take under a second.  So I figured waiting 60 seconds should deal with any reasonable attempts of the underlying stack to resolve dropped packets.  But if it's about to retry just as I'm giving up, maybe waiting a little longer might help...

Comment: So the question is then not about processing time of the message but about the expected robustness of the connection. Please update the question accordingly then. But also in this case it depends on the specific use case, i.e. direct ethernet link between peers behaves differently than a spotty mobile connection or satellite link. It is again part of the application on what is acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the TCP/IP stack (Amazon linux, in this case) end up retrying the transmission shortly after I've given up on it...?

Giving up by closing the socket will also make the underlying TCP stack stop the retransmission of unacknowledged data. This does not mean that the data are not processed by the peer though since one cannot determine if the peer failed to receive the message or one failed to receive the response.

> Is there any way to know when these occur whether they're simply caused by heavy network traffic - and will eventually succeed - or whether they're caused by a harder kind of outage, and will never get a response within a reasonable time?

No. It is up to the application protocol to handle this in a robust way, like detecting retransmission of the same message inside a newly established connection.

> I.e., is 60 seconds long enough to wait for such a data request over an existing socket - and if not, what would a better timeout value be?

To detect network connectivity problems it is better to rely on TCP keep-alive instead of waiting a specific time for a response to arrive. If the response might come late since the peer application is not responding fast enough the acceptable timeout depends on the specific use case.